# MapView in SherlockActivity

Tags: android, android-mapview, actionbarsherlock

My `MainActivity` extends `SherlockActivity` to implement the Actionbar on devices with lower Android versions.
I want to show a little `MapView` in the `MainActivity`, but apparently I need my `MainActivity` to extend `MapActivity`:

> E/AndroidRuntime(2955): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created
>   inside instances of MapActivity.

The `MapView` is inflated from an xml file.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would install the maps add-on for ActionBarSherlock and use it, presumably. See the "Google Maps" portion of http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html.

Comment: Omg, I did a quick search for 'sherlockactivity mapview' resulting in no hits, making me think this was not possible. Thanks!